# Generating word document document in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office-web-apps

I want to generate word document within the sharepoint environment programmatically. How can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal using Office XML SDK to generating document programmatically.

here is a link to download  : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124